# Can't run app on device emulator after Android Studio reinstall

Tags: android, gradle, build

I formatted my PC recently but saved my android studio projects to stick. I've now installed android studio on my fresh copy of windows and it runs fine and opens up the projects that I had previously saved.

The problem comes when I try to run the app on the device emulator I receive the error:

> Installation failed with message:
>
> > Invalid File:
> >     C:\Users******************\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slive_5.apk.

To clarify, my app is open in android studio. I click on "run app" and the emulator opens as normal but the app does not load and I receive the above error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you to clean and recompile your project first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using a supported API for the emulator and your project, also try to disable de Instant Run Feature, this issue is been reported in google forums regarding conflicts with gradle and Instant Run

Try:
app-debug.apk from command line by:

> adb install -d
>   E:\Android_Projects\yourproject\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk

Also try to disable Instant Run:

> File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run > Un-check
>   (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code)

Comment: Looks like it was an instant run issue, everything seems fine now. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Multidex applications may also give a similar error while loading on emulator. Reducing method count by optimizing dependencies could also help.